# Story ID: Drugged food makes everyone complacent

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to ID a story I read in the late 80s or early 90s. The protagonists are a group of kids who for some health or allergy reason are given natural foods. They eventually realize that they had been drugged prior to eating natural food, and further, that most other people are drugged.

I believe that the drugs are intended to make people complacent, and that on investigation, the kids learn that nobody is 'behind' this but that everybody in power is also drugged in some kind of self-perpetuating system.

Comment: Sounds interesting, but there are quite a few stories that involve drugging whole societies. If you could add more information -- maybe the name of a character or a phrase -- it would help to identify your story.

Comment: There is even a [Trope for this](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GovernmentDrugEnforcement) (warning: TVTropes!).